# How to generate TreeView of heavily nested Outlook folders?

Tags: treeview, outlook

I'm developing a standalone Outlook application.  The user needs to select an Outlook folder from a list derived from olPublicFoldersAllPublicFolder.  The selected folder could be within the root of the public folder or it could be within a subfolder of another folder.

Previously I was using the .PickFolder method of the NameSpace object.  This works, but I'd rather create my own picker dialog that's integrated into my own application.

The problem is that the public folder is heavily nested with subfolders.  Iterating through all of these in an attempt to create a TreeView object is throwing an Exchange error (I'm hitting against the RPC limit of "open" items).

So my question is, what is the best way to generate a TreeView of Outlook folders and any subfolders (which may also contain subfolders, etc. etc)?  I thought that the GetTable method of the Folders object could accomplish this, but it appears to be limited to Items and not folders.

One solution I thought of was to dynamically added a TreeViewItem that represents a subfolder each time the user expands the tree of the corresponding root folder.  But I'm somewhat lost on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this what I came up with.  There is probably a better way of handling this...but essentially I build a TreeViewItem with represents each Folder.  I want the expander graphic to be present if there exists any subfolders, but obviously I can't add the sub-folder objects yet as this will ultimately throw a RPC limit error as iterate through them.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application olApp = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application") as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace olNs;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BuildTree();
    }

    public void BuildTree()
    {
        olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        Folder rootFolder = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox) as Folder;

        TreeViewItem tvi = new TreeViewItem();
        tvi.Header = rootFolder.Name;
        tvi.Tag = rootFolder;   //store Folder object in TreeViewItem tag
        tvi.Expanded += new RoutedEventHandler(tvi_Expanded);   //Add expander event

        //Check for subfolders within this folder
        if (rootFolder.Folders.Count > 0)
        {
            //Add placeholder item to add expander graphic
            tvi.Items.Add("");
        }
        tv_MyTree.Items.Add(tvi); //main TreeView object
    }

    private void tvi_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeViewItem svi = sender as TreeViewItem;  //source/sender TreeViewItem
        svi.Expanded -= (tvi_Expanded); //Remove expander event, otherwise any expanders that are clicked later will trigger this method

        Folder f = svi.Tag as Folder;

        if (f.Folders.Count > 0)
        {
            svi.Items.Clear();  //clear list - effectively removes placeholder, rebuilds tree
            foreach (Folder sub in f.Folders)
            {
                TreeViewItem tvi = new TreeViewItem();
                tvi.Header = sub.Name;
                tvi.Tag = sub;
                tvi.Expanded += new RoutedEventHandler(tvi_Expanded);
                if (sub.Folders.Count > 0)
                {
                    tvi.Items.Add("");
                }
                svi.Items.Add(tvi);
            }
        }
    }
}
```